# Jquery selector with variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with this code line:

```
alert($('input' + ' #' + $id_bici).attr('value'));
```

the HTML code is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_bici1" name="id_bici1" value="9">
```

the alert result is "undefined"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a space between `input` and `#`. If you want the input with the specific id. Then there should not be a space between them.

```
var $id_bici = 'id_bici1'; //added for full example
alert($('input' + '#' + $id_bici).attr('value'));
```

Comment: And because it's an ID, and ID's are *unique*, you can drop input entirely from the selector and just use the ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourId = 1;
alert($('input' + '#id_bici' + yourId).attr('value'));
```

with yourId is 1 in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Element1 Element2 is a selector that selects all Element2 inside Element1. So, "input #id" will select a element with id inside inputs. It's not your case. You already know the element id. Just use it.

```
$("id_bici1")
```

See [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for a basic list of selectors.

```js
var $id_bici = "id_bici1";
    alert($('#' + $id_bici).attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="id_bici1" name="id_bici1" value="9">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
alert($('#id_bici1').attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a space too much:

```
alert($('input' + ' #' + $id_bici).attr('value'));
```

should be

```
alert($('input' + '#' + $id_bici).attr('value'));
```